# python subprocess exception

Tags: python, subprocess, snmp, net-snmp

I am using the subprocess.check_output command for two different commands and in one case I got an subprocess.CalledProcessError and in the other case not but the program crashes. The gpio482 folder does not exist and the set method returns the error and the get method crashes

Get method that catches the exception:

```
try:
    subprocess.check_output("echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio482/value", shell=True)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
    log("set state failed.")
    return "not-writable"
```

Get method that crashes:

```
    try:
    state_string = subprocess.check_output("cat /sys/class/gpio/gpio482/value", shell=True)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
    log("Get state failed.")
    return "integer", "0" # unknown
```

Is there any point which I do wrong?!

If I run the commonds in the shell I got the same error messages:

```
>>> subprocess.check_output("cat /sys/class/gpio/gpio482/value", shell=True)
cat: can't open '/sys/class/gpio/gpio482/value': No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 573, in check_output
raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'cat /sys/class/gpio/gpio482/value' 
returned non-zero exit status 1
>>> 
>>> 
>>> subprocess.check_output("echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio482/value", 
shell=True)
/bin/sh: /sys/class/gpio/gpio482/value: No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 573, in check_output
raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'echo 0 > 
/sys/class/gpio/gpio482/value' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Comment: what error message you got?

Comment: If i try both lines on the shell I got the same error messages.

Comment: Cannot reproduce your case, are you sure that your program has handle the `CalledProcessError `

Comment: When the set method catch the error I see the log message but in the get method I dont get the log message!

Comment: Ok both subprocess calls are done in different functions and when I do both calls in both function then in one function both throw the error in the other function both don't throw the exception.

Comment: When I run my script in the command line mode it works fine but the script is normaly called form net snmp and then it failed.

Answer (score 0):

The both function are shown below. The set function works fine and I catch the exception but in the get function I crashed.

```
def get_uid_light_state():
log("get_uid_light_state")

try:
    state_string = subprocess.check_output("cat /sys/class/gpio/gpio482/value", shell=True)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
    log("Get state failed.")
    return "integer", "0" 

if state_string == "1\n":
    return "integer", "2" 
elif state_string == "0\n":
    return "integer", "1" 

def set_uid_light_state(snmptype, state):
if snmptype != "integer":
    return "wrong-type"

if state == "1": 
    cmd_set_state = "echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio482/value"
elif state == "2":
    cmd_set_state = "echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio482/value"
else:
    log("Invalid value for set uid light state")
    return "wrong-value"

try:
    subprocess.check_output(cmd_set_state, shell=True)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
    log("Set state failed.")
    return "not-writable"

return "DONE"
```